# ruby+odbc+freetds MSSQL error negative string size

Tags: ruby, sql-server, odbc, dbi, freetds

so I'm executing queries in Ruby to a MS SQL database, and all is well.  I've got FreeTDS/ODBC setup and I'm laughing.  Out of no where, I get this error on one of my queries:

```
/home/jarrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in `fetch': negative string size (or size too big) (ArgumentError)
            from /home/jarrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in `fetch'
            from /home/jarrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:220:in `fetch'
```

What the?  Ok, so other queries are fine, but for some reason this one bonks.  The query is 'select * from [Provider]'.  Pretty straight forward.  The query runs on the MS SQL Server just fine.  This query used to run on another machine I had setup with Ruby + FreeTDS + ODBC.  Hmm..

I then make a quick ruby file with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'dbi'

db = DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:MYDB', 'blahblah', 'blahblah')

select = db.prepare('select * from [Provider]')
select.execute
while rec = select.fetch do
puts rec.to_s
end
db.disconnect
```

It bonks.  Then I select just a few columns (instead of *), like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'dbi'

db = DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:MYDB', 'blahblah', 'blahblah')

select = db.prepare('select Address1, Address2 from [Provider]')
select.execute
while rec = select.fetch do
puts rec.to_s
end
db.disconnect
```

And it works fine!  So, I change my query to just select the individual columns (only using about 13 columns in my query), and it's working fine.  I counted the number of total columns in the table, and there are 103.

So, I guess I'm curious: why does this bonk on me?  Is 103 columns too many to handle?

I'm running on a 64 bit Debian machine, connecting to the office via VPN (MS SQL Server machine is on office LAN).  First time I've seen an error like this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A table named "Provider" having 103 columns?

Comment: @DavidBrabant yes that's correct - Sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbi + dbd-odbc is very old and it seems not "up to date".

You should give TinyTDS a try, which implements the TDS protocol directly for ruby:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Comment: hmm..I'll have to check that out.  Thanks @Klaus